# ps working on command line but not in script

Tags: bash, shell

I have a simple script that checks the process id of some process using ps. When I run it directly on command line, it works fine but does not when I run it in a script. What am I doing wrong?

This works fine:

```
ps auwx | grep elasticsearch | grep -v grep | grep user | awk '{print $2}' | tail -1
```

In script, it does not:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Setting ES Heap to 50GB
ES_HEAP_SIZE="50g"

#Finding dump file to be deleted
FILE_ID=$(ps auwx | grep elasticsearch | grep -v grep | grep user | awk '{print $2}' | tail -1)
FILE_NAME="java_pid$FILE_ID.hprof"

echo "Elasticsearch pid: $FILE_ID"
echo "Dump file name if it exists: $FILE_NAME. Checking now."

if [ -s $FILE_NAME ]
then
  rm $FILE_NAME
  kill -9 $FILE_ID

  #Starting elasticsearch daemon
  /data/elasticsearch-1.4.4/bin/elasticsearch -d
else   
  echo "All good. Dump file $FILE_NAME does not exist."
fi
```

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: Try using absolute paths to executables.

Comment: Does your script have `elasticsearch` in the name?

Comment: Add output of `ps auwx | grep elasticsearch` to your question.

Comment: You can't use `pidof`?

Comment: Do script working directory same where the `java_pid$FILE_ID.hprof` file is? else `[ -s $FILE_NAME ]` wont work because it is a relative path. Like you do `./java_pid$FILE_ID.hprof`

Comment: I'd argue that you really should be using your operating system's process supervision system (systemd, upstart, etc), but since you're running an ElasticSearch release that's years past end-of-life, maybe there are higher priorities...

Comment: (with a supervised service correctly configured on a modern OS, it should be something like `systemctl is-active elasticsearch.service`, or `sv status elasticsearch`, or so forth; just kicking off unsupervised processes and letting them daemonize themselves is... not good).

Answer (score 0):

Personal pet peeve: why do you have six executions in your pipeline when two will handle everything you need?

```
ps auwx | awk '/elasticsearch/ && /user/ { x=$2 } END{ print x; }'
```

As an aside, you wanted PID? Because it looks like you're reading PPID.

Hope that helps.